# Problem with link

Tags: bug

If you go to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/194

and you do not have tag wiki edit privileges, you get a message, stating that, and that message has the phrase `tag wiki edit privileges` linked to the wrong place.  That link gives a description of the `trusted user` privilege.

Comment: On that page, it does talk about tag wiki edit privileges.  It is at the bottom of the page.  What would you suggest is the *right* place it should link to?

Comment: This is the right place for it, is it not?

Comment: My suggestion would be for it to link to the description of the tag wiki edit privilege, here, http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits, not the trusted user privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the confusion here is that tag wiki edit privileges are *distinct* from regular question/answer edit privileges. Users with 2k+ reputation [earn the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to make edits to normal posts without going through the suggested edits queue. But you don't get the privilege to edit tag wikis until you've reached ["Trusted User" status](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), at 20k reputation.

Of course, you only need the 20k Trusted User status to make tag wiki edits entirely on your own. Anyone can suggest edits to tag wikis, and anyone with [tag wiki edit approval privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) (5k+ reputation) can vote to approve/reject those edits in the suggested edits queue.

We don't want to *discourage* tag wiki edits, but we do want to *protect* them a little bit, since they provide an authoritative guide to the usage of a tag on Stack Overflow.

The "Trusted User" page is the one that is linked, and it does talk about tag wiki edits approximately 3/4 of the way down the page. Agreed that it is not very obvious, but I'm not sure what would be better. We could possibly create a second privileges page for tag wiki edit privileges?

Comment: Don't you get tag wiki edit privileges at 5k?  That is the privilege that I'm referring to...

Comment: No, you only get approval privileges. I modified my answer slightly.

Comment: D'oh!  And now I understand my mistake.  I didn't realize that 5k only got your tag wiki edit approvals, while you had to wait for 20k to actually edit directly.  My mistake, I'll close the question.